# How to use dynamic jenkin parallelism more efficiently?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following code, which is dynamically running the pipeline in parallel.

The issue is that the second set (group according to batchSize) is waiting until the first group completes successfully. In this way, it is taking so much time.

Is there any way I can pull one from the second group as soon as one is completed from the first group?

```
       stage('run pipelines') {
            steps {
                script {
                    runPromotionPipelines(releaseSpec)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def runPromotionPipelines(def releaseSpec) {
    def priorities = (releaseSpec.pipelines.priority as Set).sort()
    def batchSize = releaseSpec.rollout.parallelism
    priorities.each { priority ->
        releaseSpec.pipelines.findAll { it.priority == priority }.collate(batchSize).each { pipelinesBatch ->
            def promotionPipelines = [:]
            for (pipelineSpec in pipelinesBatch) {
                def pipelineName = pipelineSpec.name
                def pipelineFullPath = "${releaseSpec.promotion.targetProject}/${releaseSpec.releaseName}/$pipelineName"
                promotionPipelines[pipelineName] = {
                    runPipeline(pipelineFullPath, ['sourceProject': releaseSpec.promotion.sourceProject, 'targetProject': releaseSpec.promotion.targetProject])
                }
            }
            parallel promotionPipelines
        }
    }
}

def runPipeline(def pipelineFullPath, def parametersMap = [:]) {
    echo "starting pipeline ${pipelineFullPath}..."
    def parametersList = parametersMap.collect { [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: it.key, value: it.value] }
    build(job: pipelineFullPath, parameters: parametersList)
    echo "pipeline $pipelineFullPath completed"
}
```

Comment: I don't know of a solution to this, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. Do you need to wait on each job to complete before calling the next one? I would just schedule all the jobs to run at the same time and reply on Jenkins to schedule the jobs onto nodes correctly.